# Angular html, how to ngfor loop for nested object?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an object in our server that is like this;

```
{
    "NBA": {
        "link": "https://www.nba.com/",
        "ticketPrice": 50
    },
    "UEFA": {
        "link": "https://www.uefa.com/",
        "ticketPrice": 39
    },
    "CL": {
        "link": "https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/",
        "ticketPrice": 76
    },
    "EuroLeague": {
        "link": "https://www.euroleague.net/",
        "ticketPrice": 42
    }
}
```

I subscribe this object with this piece of code;

```
sportsObject : Sports[] //THIS IS THE MEMBER THAT SHOULD BE FILLED WITH THE JSON OBJECT GIVEN
object = Object;
ngOnInit(){
    this.SportsService.getPrices().subscribe(data=>{
      this.sportsObject = data;
    })    
}
```

And here is my html code;

```
   <div *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(sportsObject)">
       <p>The {{key}} is {{{{sportsObject[key]}}</p>
   </div>
```

But I get the "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'." error. How can I properly iterate this JSON object?

Comment: `*ngFor` only accepts arrays. You need to convert your object to iterable array.

Comment: @Kirubel how can I do that?

Comment: The json should be `{ "sports": [ "NBA": {...}, "UEFA": {...} ...  ] }` so that the service actually returns an array.

Answer (score 3):

`*ngFor` directive by default supports iterables like arrays. Here you could try to use the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe (Angular [v6.1.0+](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#610-2018-07-25)) to iterate over objects. Try the following

```html
<div *ngFor="let sport of sportsObject | keyvalue">
  <p>The {{ sport.key }} is {{ sport.value.ticketPrice }}</p>
  <p>More Info: <a [attr.href]="sport.value.link">{{ sport.value.link }}</a></p>
</div>
```

Also as a sidenote, it's generally better to avoid calling functions in directive bindings (`[dir]="someFunc()"` and `*dir="someFunc()"`) and interpolations (`{{ someFunc() }}`). The reason is if you aren't controlling the change detection strategy, then the functions would be triggered for each CD cycle and might lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your ts file hold keys as an array

```
this.sportsObject = data;
this.keys= Object.keys(data);
```

And in your template directly use this array

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <p>Key is: {{ key }}</p>
    <p>{{ sportsObject[key].link }}</p>
    <p>{{ sportsObject[key].ticketPrice }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyvalue` pipe. Also, I'd recommend to use `async` pipe instead of assigning data from the API to `sportsObject`. It could look like that:

TS:

```
sports$: Observable<Sports>;    

ngOnInit(){
  this.sports$ = this.SportsService.getPrices();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let sport of (sports$ | async) | keyvalue">
   <p>The {{sport.key}} is {{sport.value}}</p>
</div>
```